# Keep getting "There was a problem with the request" when using hubspot search api

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-cms, hubspot-api

I am doing a search on contacts and I keep getting a response of

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "There was a problem with the request.",
    "correlationId": "32073a19-9272-4955-a756-e3b6a4671738"
}
```

the correlation id keeps changing.

**This type of error response does not help determine what is going wrong.**

I am just making a simply search reguest

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/search?hapikey=MY_API_KEY' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "filterGroups": [
    {
      "filters": [
        {
          "value": "Spam (Auto Deletes Contact)",
          "propertyName": "Contact Type",
          "operator": "EQ"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "limit": 10,
  "after": 0
}'
```

**Where can I go to get some help?**

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the name of the property I was trying to find.

'Contact Type' (as shown on the HubSpot website) is actually 'contact_type' when being used in an API call.

**IF the error message had said something like 'Unknown Property' this would have helped diagnose my error **